# Background Audio for iOS Video App

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avcapturesession

So I was working on a video capture app that plays background audio (from Spotify or Apple Music) and I'm having a small problem where there's a small audio interruption when I open my app while audio is being played.

Here's what I have for allowing background audio to play (located in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in my `AppDelegate` class:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                                 withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker |     AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                                       error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Any clues to stopping that beginning interruption? Thanks!!

**EDIT**

---

I should also mention after setting the AVAudioSession I am setting my AVCaptureSession. I initialize it then set the properties.

```
self.session.usesApplicationAudioSession = YES;
self.session.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = NO;
```

Comment: Instead of passing in `nil` for the error why not use an `NSError` and see if an error is passed back?

Comment: @JAL getting no error

Comment: Have you noticed this interruption in spotify only ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless nope I get it on apple music too.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason of interruption is you are updating category in every case. You may use below function to check and update category only if it is needed.

```
-(BOOL) checkAndUpdateCategory {
    NSError *error;
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    BOOL result = [session.category isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord];
    if(!result) {
        result = [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker |  AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&error];
        if(error) {
            //Handle Error
            NSLOG(@"Error:%@", error);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, do you know what is `session.category` value when you open the app?

Comment: It stays as AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord

Comment: In this case it seems `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];` part is somehow causing the issue, but i am not sure why? Is it possible somehow to access the code from the app, i suspect something else is causing the issue to occur.

Comment: Please send to okankurtulus@gmail.com